# FireFox 4.0 'Open Link In New Window' doesn't work

Tags: windows-xp, firefox

Does anyone know why when I right-click on a link (just tested on SE links for now) in FF 4.0 and pick the 'Open Link in New Window' option that the new window just comes up empty?

The 'Open Link in New Tab' option works just fine.

Comment: Have you tried FireFox's [safe mode](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Safe%20Mode) to see if the problem remains?

Comment: @techie007, how do you know the OP is using windows-xp? (i ask this because you added that tag as an edit).

Comment: @nik - "Thanks, I'm running this on XP also. – Lance Roberts 19 hours ago" :)

Comment: @techie007, rofl! I guess, I was quite asleep then :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Mozilla forum question on these lines,
[Why does "open in new window" not work in Firefox 4](http://support.mozilla.com/oc/questions/807215)?
And, there are 8 people at this moment declaring they see the problem.

I have used Firefox 4 on Windows XP and Ubuntu Lucid till now without seeing this problem.

So, I presume you are using [Windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7), in which case you should tag your question as such.